# Убрать определенные HTML теги (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Как можно убрать `<p>` тег с помощью jQuery, но не удалять его содержимое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы сделал [более универсально](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/SgBZt/1/), на тот случай, если родительский тег неизвестен:

```
$('p').each(function(i,el){
    $(el).before($(el).text()).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов, на самом деле, очень много. Вот один из них:

```
<div id="p_tag"><p>Text</p></div>
```

...

```
var p_text = $("#p_tag").text()
$("#p_tag").text(p_tag)
```

или даже еще короче:

```
$("#p_tag").text( $("#p_tag").text() )
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще можно так: [$('p').contents().unwrap()](http://jsfiddle.net/SgBZt/2/)

Мне кажется так будет более лаконично =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").each(function(){
    var this_p = $(this);
    var text = $(this_p).text();
    $(this_p).parent().append(text);
    $(this_p).remove();
});
```

Лучше так

Comment: Чем лучше?

Comment: У Вас получается  что $(this_p) тоже самое что $($(this))

Comment: После .parent() this перескакивает на родителя, $($(this)) будет относится к p?